# Getting Started with Zend Framework2

Tags: zend-framework2

I m reading the tutorial of getting started with zend framework2, when I came to this :

[image]

I don't know how to excecute this : 
here is the link of the page : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

i have written a throughout article on how to install Zend Framework 2 on a windows environment. It is directed at Win7, but works very similar (if not identical) for XP, too.

Please read [my Blog "Zend Framework 2 Installation on Xampp for Windows"](http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best way to get started with Zend Skeleton Application is:

```
$cd my/project/dir 
$git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git --recursive
$cd ZendSkeletonApplication
```

In your project root you will find two files: **composer.json** and **composer.phar**. You can get more information about composer from the official [Getting Started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

The composer.json file describes the project's dependencies:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.4"
    }
}
```

In order to get the dependencies you need to execute from you project root:

```
$composer.phar self-update
$composer.phar update
```

Finally, you can start the internal PHP cli-server in the root directory:

```
$php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
```

I hope this will help you to install and configure your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, please check your php.exe directory. And execute it. Example:
C:\php\php.exe composer.phar self-update

If you're linux user, you already know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework 2 has just been release and it is not a framework for newbies. There are a few different ways to install which you can find on http://framework.zend.com/downloads
or with XAMPP at [Xampp In Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows)

But I have the feeling that if you are having trouble at this point then ZF2 is not for you.

Comment: I disagree. Windows users - as stupid as it sounds, but its a fact - are just not used at working with the CLI. And windows furthermore has quite some unique bullshit going on that needs to be handled. And really, this has nothing to do with programming skills :)

Answer (score 0):

Per chance if you were on a Mac or Linux box, you would open the Terminal application.  Navigate to the zend framework application (cd /path/to/app), and then run the commands.