# Composer CreateProcess Error Code 0 during Zend Framework 2 installation

Tags: xampp, zend-framework2, composer-php

I'm stuck at the first step of the Zend Framework 2 [Getting Started guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html).

**My steps:**

- I downloaded end extracted the newest version of composer to
  `c:/xampp/composer/composer.phar`
- I ran `php composer.phar
  self-update` just in case.
- I ran `php composer.phar create-project
  --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application ../htdocs/zf2-tutorial` like it is
  stated in the guide.

This is where I get this error message:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open():
CreateProcess failed, error code - 0' in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 1013`

I will add the full call Stack in the end of the question.

**What I aready tried:**

- The Guide in the answer to this question leads to the same error:
  [Installing Zend Framework 2 on XAMPP in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows)
- I freed my RAM to ~2,7 Gb avalable space
- I tried different installation guides
- I ran the CLI with admin rights

**My setup:**

- Windows 8
- PHP 5.4.4
- Composer version d017e3f2096dda7194600a76bc7328808811c8da
- Server version: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32)

**My questions:**

- Any suggestions to how to solve this problem?
- Can I install ZF2 without using composer?

---

```
Call Stack:
    0.0150     232360   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\composer.phar:0
    0.0155     231416   2. require('phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/bin/composer') C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\composer.phar:15
    0.1072    2023984   3. Composer\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
    0.1199    2234448   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
    0.2064    3173376   5. Composer\Console\Application->renderException() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:128
    0.2368    3201408   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:163
    0.2369    3202256   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:731
    0.2369    3202272   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:797
    0.2374    3202472   9. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getConsoleMode() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:827
    0.2374    3203768  10. proc_open() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1013
    0.2402    3204624  11. Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1013
```

Comment: Yes you can install ZF2 without composer. Just download the framework from https://packages.zendframework.com/ and you can download an example skeleton application to help you get started from https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication. As for the rest of your issues, I'm uncertain as I refuse to use composer =)

Comment: Thanks, it's also a nice solution. I usually prefer manual installation, because it gives you better insight into your packages and file structures. Although, this time it appeared easier to let git manage the dependencies with the --recursive option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, it was much easier than I thought:

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git --recursive
```

It installed the framework under `./vendor/ZF2/`.