# How to install zend framework 2 on window 7 with xampp 1.8.1?

Tags: windows-7, zend-framework2, xampp

I have gone through google and also through solutions provided here but I am not able to install zend framework 2.2.4 with xampp 1.8.1.

Anyone please let me know how to install this as I am currently feeling that installation of zend framework is impossible.

Comment: and what exactly is your problem? I personally dont like xampp and these kind of softwares I'd rather get myself a apache running. While it certainly is more work and somewhat of a hassle to get it running it is worth it in the end.

Comment: by doing the above process i mentioned i didnt get any index page from zf2 folder accessed?

Comment: You'll need to have a VirtualHost pointing to /zf2folder/htdocs/public in your httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: anyway thanks for your reply but when i place code for vhosts in httpd-vosts.conf and also in hosts file in windows 7. I try to start apache and click on apache button it is giving message go and check in errorlog in apache folder but when i open that file no error message is there I am following the below link:  http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Zend Framework 2 on XAMPP in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows)

Comment: i tried with the above mentioned link but no use i didnt get any error message while i am installing it

Comment: @ramsai Then you're doing something wrong. If you follow the link to my Blog, you'll get it running guaranteed. If not, you're not following my tut 100%. And there's always(!) error messages. Always. See link following foozy

Comment: Watch this youtube video, hope this will help for your issue - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARTv4yWr9Mo

Answer (score 3):

There are lots or resources out there and even if the approach of installing differs a little, it's practically all the same. And it's impossible for there not to be an error message, as all the tools used in the installation process of ZF2 on Xampp are pretty good when it comes to their respective error messages, be it appache itself, git or composer. They all give out decent error messages.

As hinted by Fozzy there's one high traffic post on ZF2 here on SO:

- [Installing Zend Framework 2 on XAMPP in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows)

And there's also another good enough tutorial over there on the official documentation from ZF2 itself (non Xampp specific)

- http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ (See Installation and the first two User Guide Chapters)