# need some assistance for zf2 installation

Tags: git, github, zend-framework2

I'm using windows 7 32-bit, and xampp 1.8.1.

I followed http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/ to install zf2.

I downloaded ***'http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe'*** and installed in "**D:\Program Files\Git**".

I installed my project by 'git' by the command-

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git F:\xampp\htdocs\zen
```

and my zend skeleton was installed in "**F:\xampphtdocszen**" folder.

the folder structures are:
[image]

now the tutorial says to type:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

these lines but when I typed

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

in git cli and pressed 'Enter' then got this error-
[image]

what should I do now to install zf2 successfully ? please tell me with detail (detail folder path,detail cli command etc.)

-Thanks.

***Edit:***

I got this error while trying-

```
php composer.phar install
```

**error:**

[image]

***RESOLVED***

I had to uncomment this line on php.ini-

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: "now the tutorial says to type:" --- in the directory with the project not in some random directory. Not sure why you need to run it under git/mingw as well

Comment: you should think a second before you run some command. If you want to become a programmer - then blindly copy-pasting commands from tutorials is a wrong way to start your career. `php composer.phar self-update` --- what does this command do?

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure for XAMPP is not rite:
Structure must be like F:\xampp\htdoc\ZendSkeletonApplication

**Steps to install zend framework 2:**

1) Git clone https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication
 (Rename the project)My project name was Zf2BlogTutorial
 C:\xampp\htdoc\Zf2BlogTutorial

2)Create a virtual host for your project(copy this code at the end of C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf  )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/Zf2BlogTutorial/public"
    ServerName local.blog
    ServerAlias local.blog
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/Zf2BlogTutorial/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

3) go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
and put this at the end:

```
127.0.0.1      local.blog
```

4) go to Zf2BlogTutorial(project folder)

5)

```
php composer.phar install

php composer.phar self-update
```

5)http://local.blog on browser and you will see zend framework 2 page