# What's the difference of "git shell" and "git"

Tags: git, zend-framework

I downloaded and installed GitHub (github.com/) on my window laptop before, so as I could share my Repositories on GitHub. From that time, I found the Git Shell has been installed on my laptop there too.

In order to install one copy of Zend Framework 2 on my local XAMPP, like [Installing Zend Framework 2 on XAMPP in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows), I need to download and intall Git from http://msysgit.github.io/.

Many people have talked about the difference between Github and Git. Like Github is one hosting service, and Git is one version control system.

But we know, Github also has tracking function. My question is where's the version control function coming from? If it's the Git Shell, then, what's the difference between Git and Git Shell? And if they are different, what's the use of Git Shell? And if they are similar, how I could use Git Shell rather than Git?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Git is the program you use for version control. (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)

You use the git-shell to "talk" to git (which you must have also installed along with everything else). It's just a more convenient shell to use for executing various git commands. (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html). You may or may not use this shell, depending on your preference. It's just an interface.

Github is a service that developers use to host their repositories.

Comment: Where's the Git the Git-shell 'talk' to before I install 'Git' respectively? Could I believe, there's already one Git on my local computer once I installed GitHub?

Comment: I think when you install the GitHub client, it installs git for you. See this https://help.github.com/articles/do-i-need-to-install-anything-extra

Comment: Dear Slider, that's just what I believe. But how I could use that Git along with GitHub, rather than to install another Git from msysgit.github.io? Actually, I have to install another Git from msysgit.github.io, because I don't know how to use the GitHub's Git at all. It's really a tragedy.

Comment: How I could config Git shortcut menu into my right-click menu?