# ZendSkeletonAplicaton giving me errors

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, xampp

I am trying to int Zend framework 2. I aready have xampp running. I followed the steps on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows?rq=1). How ever when I visit the url I specified I get the following descriptive error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\init_autoloader.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication\init_autoloader.php on line 51

as the exception states. I went on to run the command php composer.phar install 
and nothing happens. nothing displays on th cli to showing anything being installed. and when i run again application i get the same error. Where else can I look and check for errors. Thanks
I am using PHP Version 5.6.8

Comment: By 'nothing happens', do you mean it hangs, or completes with no output? Make sure you are in the application root when you run that command (`C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication` in your case). Try `php composer.phar --version`, `php composer.phar --help` to see if they give you anything. Might also be worth adding your php version to you question: `php -v`

Comment: @TimFountain It completes with no output. I did run the commands you suggested and still no output. I have version 5.6.8. Thanks.

Comment: Howabout `php composer.phar -vvv install`?

Comment: still didn't come right. But got it to work after starting afresh

Answer (score 1):

So what worked for me. I began again from scratch following the tutorial [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)

Then I still got a "could not open input file: composer.phar" when I ran the command: `php composer.phar install`

so according to "www.softanalyst.com/zend-2-framework-installation-with-xampp/#comment-883" I need to run the following command:

> php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

which I did and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

open up your terminal and move To your project using the `cd project directory`

one type `dir composer.phpr` and try this one `dir composer.json` if  both file listed than do the next step otherwise download the composer in current directory and run the following command as bellow.

`php composer.phar install` this comman will install all required dependency from the `composer.json` file. it will take time as depend on internet speed.

once it's complete than try [this link for further steps](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html).this link also having how To install composer And skeleton application.

[Github](https://github.com/vrkansagara) 
 [Twitter](https://twitter.com/vrkansagara)